# Differential form TQFT for Walker-Wang model?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-field-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory

In terms of the TQFTs in continuous differential form gauge fields, what would the [Walker-Wang lattice model](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Walker-Wang+model) describe? Obviously, there is a $BF$ theory part:

$$\frac{N}{2 \pi}\int B dA$$

if it contains the discrete $\mathbb{Z}_N$ gauge fields. But what else does the model contain, in any dimensions, or in 3+1d?

They mention the non Abelian BF+BB theory in their paper, but is that TQFT really a part of their model?

$$\frac{N}{2 \pi}\int Tr[ B \wedge dA + (\Lambda/12) B \wedge B ]$$
$$\frac{N}{2 \pi}\int  Tr[ B \wedge dA + F \wedge F] $$

There is no explicit argument why such a continuous TQFT shows up from the discrete Walker-Wang lattice model. Are threre complete or partial lists of such differential form TQFTs for Walker-Wang model? What are they?

p.s. Please DO correct my TQFT quantization factor if it is wrong. I copied down from their paper. Thank you.